# Bash script to ping host with while condition

Tags: bash, while-loop, ping

First, I would like to say that I know nothing about bash but I am trying to learn through practice.

So, I am trying to make a script which will send a magic packet to a remote host. While the remote host is starting I would like to print dots on the display.

I really don't have a problem with the wakeonlan part and of course I don't really need a script to do that. However, in order to learn something useful I try to make a script.

So my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash 

! timeout 0.5 ping -c1 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Host is up"
else
    wakeonlan FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
    echo "Host is starting ..." 
    while ! ping -c1 -w1 -n 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null 2&>1
    do
            printf "%c" "."
    done
    echo "Host is up!\n\n"

fi
exit 0
```

Now when the host is already up the while loop exits without printing. But when the host is down it outputs **infinetely** dots on the display, even if the host is up.
I really don't understand why the while loop does not stop when the condition is met.

I would appreciate your answer, especially if its aligned with my implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I just did that. There are two recommendations.
1. `2&>1` This is a file redirection. Was it supposed to be a comparison or fd operation?
2.`echo "Host is up!\n\n"` echo may not expand escape sequences. Use printf.

For the first, I aimed to do an fd operation. Is it not correct? The second one. I should better use printf. But this isn't really the problem

So it must be the fd operation. I don't understand why it's wrong.

Comment: Really useful your link @Cyrus

Comment: The redirect `2&>1` (on the second `ping` command) should be `2>&1`. I'm not entirely sure how bash parses it the way you have it, but I'm fairly sure you now have a file named "1" that output got redirected to. (Its contents might actually be informative -- take a look before deleting it.)

Comment: Not to answer your question, but you might want `until ping -c1 -w1 -n 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null 2>&1` for better understanding.

Comment: upvoting for better than average early Q and your ability to follow instructions ;-) . You'll get there. Good luck.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you I noticed that a couple ago. Is `command &> \dev\null` different from `command > \dev\null 2>&1`  different from `command &> \dev\null 2>&1`?
@shellter so many operators, so little time, what can I do?

Comment: `&>` is a bash shorthand for "redirect both stdout and stdin to...". That means `&> \dev\null` is sufficient to discard both stdout and stderr (equivalent to `> /dev/null 2>&1`), but is not portable to other shells. `&> \dev\null 2>&1` sends both stdout and stderr to /dev/null, and then redirects stderr to stdout; since they were both already going to the same place, that second redirect is completely redundant.

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson for the explanation. It is much more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured out what's going on here. In the command

```
while ! ping -c1 -w1 -n 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null 2&>1
```

the `&` and `>` are in the wrong order. This causes a chain reaction of confusion and unexpected interpretations.

Specifically, bash parses `2&>1` as the argument "`2`" followed by the redirect `&>1` which sents both stdout and stderr into a file named "1". So it runs this command, with all output to "1":

```
ping -c1 -w1 -n 8.8.8.8 2
```

Some versions of `ping` will give an error/usage message here, because they only accept a single target IP address (and then exit with an error status, making your loop run forever).

Other versions will interpret `8.8.8.8` as a hop to use on the way to the final destination `2`, which is an old shorthand for the IP address `0.0.0.2`. Which doesn't actually exist on the Internet. Which means the `ping` will fail and exit with an error status, making your loop run forever.

I suspect if you look in the file "1", you'll be able to tell which of these (or possibly something else) is happening.

There are some scripting lessons to be learned here:

- All those cryptic piles of symbols *matter*, and if you get them a little bit wrong you can wind up doing something very different from what you intended.
- Discarding output (especially error output) is a good way to hide what's going wrong. If a script is having trouble, capture & examine any errors its components produce.
- `set -x` tells the shell to print what it thinks it's executing as it runs commands, and putting that before problem sections in scripts (and `set +x` afterward to turn it off) is a good say to find out what's going on. This is how I figured out that bash was treating "`2`" as an argument rather than part of the redirect.
- [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is handy!

Comment: Well I did have a file named "1" in my folder which contained the result from ping.
Another question relative to my script is related to the condition of while. 

The way I understand it, is that the `ping` command displays a string and not a true / false bit. So if the output of `ping` is  a string why would `while` accept it as a true / false switch?

Comment: @ginos Commands can "return" three standard kinds of results: what they print to stdout (which is often text, but can be an arbitrary stream of data), what they print to stderr (normally text, but in principle could also be arbitrary data), and an "exit status" (which is a small integer, and generally indicates whether the command succeeded (zero) or failed (nonzero)). What you see in the terminal (or gets redirected to files) is stdout and/or stderr. What `while` looks at is the success/failure indication from the exit status.